# Take a screenshot on chromebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

I have a chrome extension that when it receives a message from an application, it makes a screenshot. But I want to make a capture even of the desktop, or of any screen that is not of the navigator. I've used chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab and html2canvas, but that's not what I'm looking for, because they just do a browser capture. Is there any way to be able to take screenshots of the desktop? Thank you.

Comment: See [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) and [demo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:desktopcapture)

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, but I need it to be transparent to the user, and with desktopCapture API the user is required to accept the screenshot.

Comment: Chrome explicitly and intentionally doesn't allow automated screenshots. You'll have to use a separate utility and communicate with it via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm: Hi, Can you please share any referenced document where its mentioned that "Chromebook explicitly and intentionally doesn't allow automated screenshots"? If yes please share I am searching it but no luck?

Comment: My comment says "Chome", not "Chromebook". I don't have a reference at hand, but you can look at https://crbug.com. I just remember the security around these APIs was tightened to prevent data stealing.